# How can i put ajax in confirm button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

Hi friends i am trying to put ajax url in confirm button to update something in Database.

So i do this in JavaScript Section

```
function freeze_account() {
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm!',
        content: 'This dialog will automatically trigger \'cancel\' in 6 seconds if you don\'t respond.',
        type: 'red',
        typeAnimated: true,
        boxWidth: '30%',
        useBootstrap: false,
        buttons: {
            confirm: function() {
                var manager_id = $('#manager_id').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "update_freeze.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        'manager_id': manager_id
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            },
            cancel: function() {}
        }
    });
}
```

and this is code for update

```
$manager_id = $_POST['manager_id'];
$state = '0';
$update=runQuery("UPDATE `users` SET `userStatus` =:userS WHERE `userID`=:user_id");
$update->bindparam(":userS",$state);
$update->bindparam(":user_id",$manager_id);
            $update->execute();
```

My problem is when i press confirm button ajax works and go to another page but nothing happen in database.
What is wrong in my code Or Maybe I miss something?

any help any idea i will be grateful

Best Regards

Comment: Use your debugging tools. Fiddler to see if the request is sent. The F12 debugging tools of Chrome to breakpoint your code and see what is going on.

Comment: Should be `$('#manager_id').val()`  instead of `('#manager_id').value`

Comment: @Satpal: Well spotted :)

Comment: Where do you bind this code to that submit button? You should bind an event handler to the button like so `$(".the_button").on("click", freeze_account);` Or if you already did that, where do you execute this function?

Comment: this function i call it when i click in li tag by onclick function 

       `<li onClick="freeze_account();" id="freeze_account"`

@GerritLuimstra

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Like calls to undefined functions etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look how i solved my problem 
Maybe one benefit of my code
Thanks for every one suggestions or helping me

```
function freeze_account() {


            var pid = $('#manager_id').val();


            bootbox.dialog({
              message: "Are you sure you want to Freeze this account ?",
              title: "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Freeze !",
              buttons: {
                success: {
                  label: "No",
                  className: "btn-success",
                  callback: function() {
                     $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                  }
                },
                danger: {
                  label: "Freeze!",
                  className: "btn-danger",
                  callback: function() {




                      $.post('update_freeze.php', { 'pid':pid })
                      .done(function(response){
                          bootbox.alert(response);

                          location.reload();
                      })
                      .fail(function(){
                          bootbox.alert('Something Went Wrog ....');
                      })

                  }
                }
              }
            });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an event listener on your button. Firstly, ensure you have an ID on your button so we can grab it.

Now, we create the event listener:

```
$("#button").on("click", freeze_account());
```

And, now when you click the button the ajax call should go through successfully.

However, it will still redirect yo due to its default behaviour.

To override this, simply prevent the default event:

```
function freeze_account(event) {

    event.preventDefault(); // stops the button redirecting

    $.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm!',
        content: 'This dialog will automatically trigger \'cancel\' in 6 seconds if you don\'t respond.',
        type: 'red',
        typeAnimated: true,
        boxWidth: '30%',
        useBootstrap: false,
        buttons: {
            confirm: function() {
                var manager_id = $('#manager_id').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "update_freeze.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        'manager_id': manager_id
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            },
            cancel: function() {}
        }
    });
}
```